# Call REST on shutdown

Tags: linux, init.d

I would like to know whats the best way to call a REST web service when a Linux server is shutting down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Debian/Ubuntu based linux distros just;

Write a script, give it a name i.e. all_hail_lord_cthulu.sh in the the example below, then run;

```
update-rc.d -f all_hail_lord_cthulu.sh reboot 90 0 6 .
```

For RHEL based linux distros it's a bit more flexible/complex - have a look [HERE](http://shabirimam.wordpress.com/2009/03/10/adding-script-to-run-at-startup-or-shutdown/)